# Replace an inner function call and make it return a default value for testing

Tags: python, python-unittest

```
def func(o_dict):
   id = o_dict.get("id")
   
   res = func2()  # other func - inner call
```

Can I declare a default value for the inner function call from my test class?

I am testing `func()` and I can't test the inner function (it is an HTTP call with an API that doesn't exist yet).

I need to return 200 from the inner function call to test `func()` without changing the code at the inner function (this case it is easy to return 200, but with a lot of function tests it difficult to change all and remember to remove them when the test is finished).

Comment: try to mock it. see https://www.fugue.co/blog/2016-02-11-python-mocking-101

Comment: Awesome!!! this is the solution. 
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a test using mocking

func.py:

```
def func2():
    raise Error()

def func(o_dict):
    id = o_dict.get("id")

    res = func2()  # other func - inner call
    return res
```

your test file:

```
from unittest.mock import patch
from func import func

@patch('func.func2', return_value=200)
def test_func2(patched_func2):
    actual_result = func({})

    assert actual_result == 200
    # if you want make sure the mocked function is called
    mocked_func2.assert_called_once()
```